# when i click on anchor i need to enable text field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a anchor tag, with id="click_me". When i click on this i should enable input text (`<input type="text" id="summary" class="summary">`), which is disabled first.

even i can do it using javascript function, by calling these javascript function() using onclick in the  tag; but in my application i shld not use these.

I am newbie to php. please suggest me any alternative solution either using DOM or anything else.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use JavaScript in your application? Compatibility issues? This is possible using only PHP and HTML links, but it's complex because presumably, you'll need to store what the user has entered so far.

Comment: @Pekka: I think he means he can't use inline (obtrusive) JS.

Comment: The clicking is done client-sided, outside PHP's control (it has sent the HTML and the process is finished). The only way PHP can do this if you want to reload the _whole_ page on a click on the link, and alter the output not to add the 'disabled' attribute (possibly on the basis of a GET variable). This seems not very user-friendly to me, and I wouldn't use PHP this way.

Comment: @Wrikken but it's the only way if he really can't use JavaScript, and if implemented properly, it's not that user-unfriendly. It just flickers a second longer

Comment: Basically you need to manipulate one element in response to something that has happened on another element. So I can't see how this can be got away without javascript.

Comment: @Orange it's easily possible by making the link a submit button, and submitting the whole form. I would just like to know first whether this is really *necessary*. @Josh true, that's one possible interpretation :) The OP needs to be more clear here

Comment: @Pekka, true, and providing a non-javascript fallback would be nice, but depending on the audience that 'second' could be quite some seconds in low-bandwidth areas. Best to have a less bandwidth-intensive alternative.

Comment: @Pekka rite. although, submitting the thing would seems outrightly odd. Is it possible thru CSS? where this link is having a large background and upon clicking, its background goes off, and we see the text box that was hidden behind it? And the link doesn't go anywhere

Comment: @OrangeRind nice idea! But I don't think it can be done in pure CSS, it can't be made to react to clicks as it can to the mouse cursor hovering over an element

Comment: @sandeep Do clarify regarding the javascript factor. (question thoda clear karo yaar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('#click_me').click(function() {
  $('select-your-input-element-here').attr('disabled','');
});
```

Comment: He can't use Javascript, so use jQuery instead?

Comment: It's tagged jQuery - I think he means "I shouldn't be using inline javascript"

Comment: @Mez yeah, true. The question could use some clarification

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#click_me").toggle( 
function () 
{ 
    $('#your_input_box').attr("disabled", true); 
}, 
function () 
{ 
    $('#your_input_box').removeAttr("disabled"); 
});
```

would possibly do the trick in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Having this somewhere in your `<head>` section will work:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#click_me').click( function() {
        $('#textarea').removeAttr("disabled");
    };
});
</script>
```